# Reading deeply nested Json objects with Python

Tags: python, json

I want to read the value of a deeply nested Json object. I am interested in reaching the `temperature` value.

```
{
    "weatherChannel": [
       {
           "week": {  
                "location": [
                    {
                        "info": [ 
                            {
                                "temperature": 5
                            }
                         ]
                     }
                 ]
            } 
        }
     ]
 }
```

I am capable of reaching the `location` information by doing: `weatherChannel['week']['location']` but I am unable to go further down.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean *"unable"*? `weatherChannel['week']['location']` is an array, but the fact that you got that far suggests that you know how to get objects out of an array.

Comment: Yes, jonrsharpe hits the nail on the head, you've mixed contents here - so your weatherChannel object consists of a list, the first element of which contains a dictionary, of which, "week" is a key, then there's a subdictionary with "location" as a key, and then inside that, it's another list, containing a dictionary of which the "info" key returns a collection - this list has a first element that is another dictionary, containing the key of "temperature". You want something like `weatherChannel[0]["week"]["location"][0]["info"][0]["temperature"]`.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Yes an oversight from my end. Appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {
     "weatherChannel": [
        {
            "week": {  
                 "location": [
                     {
                         "info": [ 
                             {
                                 "temperature": 5
                             }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
             } 
         }
      ]
  }

d["weatherChannel"][0]["week"]["location"][0]["info"][0]["temperature"]
```

That provides what you need. You need to understand that `[]` denotes List and you access to List elements through their position (first position is 0, not 1). While `{}` denotes dictionary which contains pairs `key:value` like for example `"temperature":5` and you access the values through their keys.

Answer (score -1):

weatherChannel contains a list so is will be `weatherChannel[0]["week"]["location"]`